# Graph distance in vertex-transitive graphs

Tags: probability, graph-theory, random-walk

Let $G=(V,E)$ be an infinite, vertex-transitive, connected graph of finite degree.
Let $0$ be a vertex. Let $d(x,y)$ be the graph distance between two vertices $x$ and $y$, i.e., the length of the shortest path that connects $x$ to $y$.
Is it true that for any $x \in V$ there exists $ y \in V$ such that 
$$
\{y, x\} \in E,
$$
and
$$
d(y,0) = d(x,0) + 1?
$$

It seems to me that it is true in wide generality under the assumptions above (think of $\mathbb{Z}^d$ or trees), but I cannot prove it. Is it maybe necessary to assume a Cayley structure to make it true?

Answer (score 1):

This seems false for graph with a leaf $x$.Take $o$ to be any other vertex. Then, by definition there is a unique vertex $y$ with $\{x,y\} \in E$ and for such $x$, $d(y,0) = d(x,0) - 1$.

Comment: What is precisely a graph with a leaf $x$? I asked for infinite, vertex-transitive graphs.

Comment: Perhaps I should have added "connected". I add it in the post.

Comment: I am sorry, I did assume that "vertex-transitive" meant "connected". Do you mean something else ?

Comment: @QuantumLogarithm : a leaf is a vertex of degree $1$.